# list index out of range querying UV index from device

Tags: python, json, raspberry-pi

Im new to python and playing with my raspberry-pi to pull some data out of my homewizard device.
I want to receive the UV index with json from the device using this python script.
My goal is to query al the uv data and put it in a existing weatherview sqlite database but to start I need to receive the correct values

```
import requests
r=requests.get('http://<ip>/<password>/uvlist')
uv=r.json
print uv['response'][2]['uv']
```

When running the above script I get this error

```
sudo python uv.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "uv.py", line 4, in <module>
    print uv['response'][2]['uv']
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Typing the url in my browser gives me the json code below.

```
{
status: "ok",
version: "2.352",
request: {
route: "/uvlist"
},
response: [
{
id: 2,
name: "UV",
favorite: "no",
uv: 3.9,
uv+: 6.5,
uv+t: "13:18"
}
]
}
```

Can anyone help me out ?

thanks in advance,

Edwin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `uv['response']` is a list of dictionaries, You can access `uv` this way:

```
print uv['response'][0].get('uv')
```